# command line output validation in c#

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

My output in the actual command prompt looks like this:

```
Name:   My Software
Version:  1.0.1
Installed location: c:\my folder
```

I am trying to get this output via c# code

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "my command to execute");   

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();

// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string[] lines = result.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine, }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach (string tmp in lines)
{
    if (tmp.Contains("Version"))
    {
        isAvailable= true; 
    }
}
```

I don't want to just check a version tag, I am trying to get the version value and do a compare, for example if the value is 1.0.1, i would want that value and do a comparison with 2.0.0.

I can use `indexof`(like `result.IndexOf("Version:");`) - But that doesn't get me the value of the version

Any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below... it will help you...

Instead of `Contains` check the word by using `IndexOf`...

```
if (tmp.IndexOf("Version") != -1)
{
isAvailable = true;
string[] info = tmp.Split(':');
string version = info[1].Trim();
Console.WriteLine(version);
}
```

Comment: The above piece gets me the version value, and all the answers were helpful, thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [.NET Version class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxyt63s.aspx) and it's [CompareTo(Object) method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3bf0xb2.aspx) to do your comparison.

```
var input = new Regex(@"(?<=Version:)\s*(.*)").Matches(@"Name:   My Software
Version:  1.0.1
Installed location: c:\my folder")[0].Value.Trim();

var a = new Version(input);
var b = new Version("2.0.0");

int comparison = a.CompareTo(b);

if(comparison > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + " is a greater version.");
} 
else if(comparison == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + " and " + b +" are the same version.");
}   
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(b + " is a greater version.");
}
```

Comment: 1.0.1 getting that value is the challenge am facing.

Comment: @Sharpeye500 I updated it with a slightly modified regex of what csharpler used in their answer

Answer (score 1):

```
string versionText;
var stuff = tmp.Split(":");
if(stuff[0].Trim() == "Version")
{
    isAvailable = true;
    versionText = stuff[1].Trim();
}

if(versionText == expectedVersionText)  // Do something specfic.
```

Comment: You should consider using `.Trim()`s to remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Regular Expressions:

```
^Version:\s*(.*)$
```

should match the version number inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string sought = "Version:";
            foreach (string tmp in lines)
            {
                if (tmp.Contains(sought))
                {
                    int position = tmp.IndexOf(sought) + sought.Length;
                    string version = tmp.Substring(tmp.IndexOf(sought) + sought.Length);
                    string[] versionParts = version.Split('.');
                    VersionCompare(versionParts, new string[]{"2", "0", "0"});
                }
            }
/// <summary>Returns 0 if the two versions are equal, else a negative number if the first is smaller, or a positive value if the first is larder and the second is smaller.</summary>
private int VersionCompare(string[] left, string[] right)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(left.Length, right.Length); ++i)
    {
        int leftValue = int.Parse(left[i]), rightValue = int.Parse(right[i]);
        if(leftValue != rightValue) return leftValue - rightValue;
    }
    return left.Length - right.Length;
}
```